# How can I open vi editor from my java application in the same terminal?

Tags: java, linux

How can I open `vi` editor from my java application? 
I have already tried this

```
Process p = new ProcessBuilder("xterm","-e","vi /backup/xyz/test/abc.txt").start();  

int exitVal = p.waitFor();
System.out.println("Exited with error code "+exitVal);
```

But this opens `vi` in a new terminal. **I want the vi editor to open in the same terminal that my application is running**

Comment: Is the Java process running on the same machine that VI is installed on?

Answer (score 2):

Should be simple: leave out the xterm, just start vi:

```
Process p = new ProcessBuilder("vi", "/backup/xyz/test/abc.txt").start();
```

If you want more command line arguments for vi, add them as separate strings, not inside the "" of first argument.

And launching a terminal program like vi naturally requires, that you started the java app from visible terminal, so vi has a terminal to use, but I assume this is so.

Comment: So if I just use 
Process p = new ProcessBuilder("vi /backup/xyz/test/abc.txt").start();  

It compiles but while running it gives me this error

Cannot run program "vi /backup/xyz/test/abc": java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory

Comment: @san2505 I made answer more specific

Comment: @san2505 - you probably have to use a path that actually exists on your machine.  I believe that was just an example...

Comment: You forgot a comma. A working version would be `p = new ProcessBuilder("vi", "/backup/xyz/test/abc.txt").start();` I suppose.

Comment: I m actually using a VM to run this application. Is it the case that I need to specify a proper path for vi command as well?

Comment: But when I run this command, it hangs and do nothing. I think the vi start running in the background. Is there a way to pull it o the same terminal ?

Comment: What happens if you press ctrl-C on the terminal so Java program is terminated, and then run vi from command line?

Answer (score 2):

The problem was highlighted here:

[How can I launch VI from within Java under commons-exec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9690702/how-can-i-launch-vi-from-within-java-under-commons-exec)

However since Java 1.7 you can use the next example to transparently redirect and have full console functionality

```
    System.out.println("STARTING VI");
     ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("/usr/bin/vi");
     processBuilder.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
     processBuilder.redirectError(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
     processBuilder.redirectInput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);

     Process p = processBuilder.start();
      // wait for termination.
      p.waitFor();
    System.out.println("Exiting VI");
```

This will allow you to open VI transparently.